# Issue in Dynamic loading ActiveX in VB6.0

Tags: vb6, activex

I have following method which I am using to load ActiveX control dynamically,

```
Dim ctl As Control
Set ctl = Form1.Controls.Add("prog.id", "myctl")
ctl.Visible = True
```

Using this code control successfully display on the form, but when I try to access methods/properties of control `ctl.mymethod()` its give the error, “Object doesn’t support this method or property".

Secondly when I use this approach

```
Dim ctl As Object
Set ctl = CreateObject("prog.id")
Ctl.mymethod()
```

Here method successfully called from control, but I can’t display this object on form.

Kindly tell me any solution about this issue.

**Edit:**

Using the following approch its also giving the error when I call methods, "Object does't support........"

```
Dim ctl As Object
Set ctl = Controls.Add("prog.id", "myctl")
ctl.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't declare the reference as `Control`. That will only let you access the `Control` interface members.
Try declaring `ctl` as `Object` instead and it will then be fully late bound.

```
Dim ctl As Object
Set ctl = Controls.Add("COMCTL.ListViewCtrl", "myctl")
ctl.Visible = True
ctl.View = 2
ctl.ListItems.Add , , "123"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but using 2nd approach how I can add this control on form?

Comment: You can't, you need to use `Controls.Add` to add a control to a form at runtime.

Comment: Works for me. You're going to need to give more inclusive code samples if you want further help though. (It also works declaring it as `Control`)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a type library (.tlb) for the control, add a reference to it and try this

```
Dim ctl As prog.id
Set ctl = Controls.Add("prog.id", "myctl").Object
ctl.mymethod
```

Notice usage of `.Object` property.

Comment: I don't have .tlb file only OCX which is register on system. I want to access the properties of ActiveX, In ActiveX I use this approch to exposing the properties **Public Property Let ShowSelection(bShow As Boolean)**

Comment: how can I get tlb file from ocx file?

Comment: @Siddiqui If the OCX was created with VB6 then it has an embedded TypeLib.  Did you add a reference to the ocx to your project?  If you did, you can hit F2 and use the Object Browser view and you should see your control, and you should be able to references it by type name in code.